window.location showing old value after redirect from authentication server
I am using keycloak as authentication server for my react app. The authentication flow is:

App displays a login button. When clicked, url gets changed for that of keycloak with a redirect on /auth/callback
/auth/callback uses the component Callback, that given the url search params finishes the authentication.

My problem is that keycloak returns a successful authentication and a redirect to callback, but in callback the url detected is still that of "/login". This is the contents of my callback component
const Callback = () => {
    const { keycloakClient } = useKeycloak();
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.info(window.location);
        const getTokens = async () => {
            await keycloakClient.authenticate();
            setAuthenticated(keycloakClient.authenticated());
        };
        getTokens();
    }, []);

    if (authenticated) {
        setHeadersInterceptor(keycloakClient);
        return <Navigate to="/todolists" replace />;
    } else {
        return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
    }
};

and this component is only referenced in a route for /auth/callback. How is possible that when printing window.location, I am still getting /login instead of /auth/callback?

The problem seems to be related to the asynchronous nature of react / javascript. Should I use, instead of windows.location, the useLocation hook, then I get the expected values.
